# how to plot mean and standard deviation of multiple measures in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I'd like to plot mean and standard deviation of multiple measures in one Gnuplot, if possible.

For example, object A and B has measures of lengths and weights like this (CSV format):

```
length,weight
100.0,0.1
100.5,0.12
98.8,0.09
100.1,0.11
```

Is it possible to plot this in a single figure with good visibility, i.e., the length is at the magnitude of 100, while the weight is at 0.1? I don't want the logarithmic way because in my real data, it doesn't make sense to logarithmize them.

Yerrorlines seems an option, but can histogram do this too?
Anyone knows how to do so in Gnuplot?
Thanks!

Comment: Maybe a boxplot fits your needs: http://www.gnuplot.info/demo/boxplot.html. To get length and weight on different scales you would have to use two y-axes (`set y2tics` and `plot ... axes x1y2`).